# I am trying to write a bash script to update package.json dependency version

Tags: json, bash, shell, automation

This is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "project-1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "TestCafe project",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "ci:build": "npm ci",
        "test": "testcafe",
        "precise-commits": "precise-commits"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "http://github.com/dev/test/testcafe-test"
    },
    "author": "Tom",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "precise-commits": "^1.0.2",
        "prettier": "^1.16.4",
        "random-words": "^1.1.0",
        "testcafe": "^1.8.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "page-objects": "1.6.169"
    }
}
```

I need to update page-objects version from 1.6.169 to 1.6.170 and as and when we make changes to page objects version changes
this is the bash file i have written

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJECT=${1?Error: No test project directory passed}
NEW_VERSION=${2?Error: Pass new version}
echo "Updating page object version for ${PROJECT} project"

cd ~/git/master/test/${PROJECT}
CURRENT_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")  # here it gives me the 
# version of json which is 1.0.0 but i need 1.6.169
sed -i '' "s/${CURRENT_VERSION}/${NEW_VERSION}/" package.json
echo $CURRENT_VERSION
#npm i
```

how can i get 1.6.69?

Comment: Tip: Use [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net). It won’t solve this problem, but it will help you avoid numerous potential bugs in your script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(grep -o '"page-objects": "[^"]*' package.json | grep -o '[^"]*$') worked for me.
thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem where i had to update version of package.json for our library that i maintain. What i done is something similar to what you have done

```
#!/bin/bash
NEW_VERSION=${1?Error: Pass new version}
CURRENT_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version") 


sed -i '' "s/${CURRENT_VERSION}/${NEW_VERSION}/" package.json
cat package.json
```

Comment: @ Zeljko Marinkovic, this helpmed me for my problem, but this is replacing the all occurrences like in dependencies in package.json as well, Can you help me out to change only the version in package.json

Comment: If you never update the version field and have the default `0.0.1`, you can do like I am doing. I am using something like this to change the version: `sed -i '/"version": *"0.0.1"/ s/"0.0.1"/"'$NEW_VERSION_WITHOUT_V'"/' package.json`

Answer (score 3):

Sed is an efficient stream editor for filtering and transforming text. It has great ability to filter text in a pipeline unlike other editors. However, considering the content of your package.json, it is more preferable to use a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor. For instance, you can make use of `jq` with a temporary file like as shown below to get an in-place replace editing effect. It is like `sed` for JSON data - you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that sed, awk, grep and friends let you play with text.

```sh
tmp=$(mktemp)
jq '.dependencies."page-objects"="1.6.170"' package.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" package.json
```

If you want to avoid hard-coded version, pass the correct version via a `jq` argument:

```sh
version="1.6.172"
tmp=$(mktemp)
jq --arg version "$version" '.dependencies."page-objects"=$version' package.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" package.json
```

`jq` is written in C and has no runtime dependencies, so it should be possible to build it for nearly any platform. Prebuilt binaries are available for Linux, OS X and Windows. You can check more details bout jq [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) if you're interested. If jq is not installed on your machine, you can easily grab it from [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).

Comment: `jq` has split and built-in arithmetic to increment the patch version as well.

Comment: What an elegant solution, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is great for editing text, but unsuitable for editing JSON. You could give [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) a try instead.

To change `"1.6.169"` to `"1.6.170"`:

```
xidel -s package.json -e '($json).dependencies.page-objects:="1.6.170"'
```

Within your bash-script you could use...

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJECT=${1?Error: No test project directory passed}
NEW_VERSION=${2?Error: Pass new version}
echo "Updating page object version for ${PROJECT} project"

cd ~/git/master/test/${PROJECT}
xidel -s package.json --in-place -e '($json).dependencies.page-objects:="'$NEW_VERSION'"'
#npm i
```

...to update the page-objects version and overwrite *'package.json'*.

Comment: thank you. but its stdout the result rather than updating in place.

Comment: @notfluffy With `--in-place`, as shown in the 2nd codeblock, I'll update your 'package.json'.

Comment: I got xidel: not found